# Horizontal scrolling using positions and swiping

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm having an issue transforming my horizontal scroll logic into positional one. To summarize my problem; I have a div which has overflowing elements, which need to be scrollable, but not with scrollbars/overflow, but position:left. I had OK solutions, but it all went downhill after resetting on click.

The following snippet is where I was left stranded, when you click and drag the child, it should act the same as if you were horizontally scrolling.

Also, please note, I must use mousedown/mousemove/mouseup events so that I can port the logic over to touch

Thanks in advance!

```js
var $scrollWithin = $('#child');

var clicked = false, clickX;
$(document).on({
    'mousemove': function(e) {
        clicked && updateScrollPos(e);
    },
    'mousedown': function(e) {
        clicked = true;
        clickX = e.pageX;
    },
    'mouseup': function() {
        clicked = false;
    }
});

var lastLeft = 0;
var updateScrollPos = function(e) {
    
    var left = lastLeft + (clickX - e.pageX);
    
    $scrollWithin.css('left', left + 'px');
    lastLeft = left;
}
```

```css
#child {
height:200px;
width:4000px;
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%,rgba(0,80,255,1) 100%);
position:relative;
}


#parent {
  width:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:solid 4px #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="parent">
<div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may want to check out https://ilyashubin.github.io/scrollbooster/

Comment: Unforunately I can not use any other external libraries, it has to be done with js and jquery, but thatnks for the suggestion. I'm pretty sure it's just the math that I keep getting wrong, I'm sure someone on here has a bit more brain power about the case.

Comment: @Chance Also, I have actually tried it, but it makes content unclickable, tried plenty of things and it's simply not working, albeit scrolling and everything works perfectly